# Não consigo cadastrar dados usando webservice Rest JAVA

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, rest

Ao cadastrar dados no meu banco de dados usando webservice ocorre o seguinte erro.

```
Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
Post parameters : {"login":"felipe10","senha":"1234","email":"teste@gmail.com","perfil":"teste100"}
Response Code : 415
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1938)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.sendPost(HttpExemplo.java:165)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.main(HttpExemplo.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at consumindows.HttpExemplo.sendPost(HttpExemplo.java:159)
... 1 more
```

REST Web Service

```
    package ws;

  import com.google.gson.Gson;
  import dao.UsuarioDAO;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
  import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
  import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
  import javax.ws.rs.POST;
  import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
  import modelo.Usuario;

   /**
   * REST Web Service
   *
  * @author Felipe
   */
  @Path("fazenda")
  public class FazendaWS {

@Context
private UriInfo context;


public FazendaWS() {
    @POST
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Path("Usuario/inserir")

public boolean inserir(String content){
 Gson g = new Gson();
Usuario u = (Usuario) g.fromJson(content, Usuario.class);
    UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();  
    return dao.inserir(u);
         }
     }
   }
```

httpExemplo

```
 package consumindows;

  import com.google.gson.Gson;
 import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Proxy.Type;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import modelo.Usuario;


public class HttpExemplo {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        HttpExemplo http = new HttpExemplo();

            Gson g =new Gson();
            Usuario u = new Usuario();

            java.lang.reflect.Type usuarioType= new TypeToken<Usuario>() {}.getType();
            String url;


u.setEmail("teste@gmail.com");
    u.setLogin("felipe10");
    u.setPerfil("teste100");
    u.setSenha("1234");
    System.out.println(u.getLogin()); 

     String json=g.toJson(u, usuarioType);

    url="http://localhost:8080/FazendaWS/webresources/fazenda/Usuario/inserir";
               http.sendPost(url,json,"POST");
   }

    // HTTP POST request
private void sendPost(String url,String urlParameters,String method) throws Exception {

    URL obj= new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod(method);
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "application/json");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    //String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro 415 do http é quando o provedor do serviço, no caso seu webservice, não suporta o formato do dado enviado, no caso o json.

Na linha:
`con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "application/json");`

Muda para:
`con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Deve resolver o problema do erro 415.